# How to only return a flow of list when certain condition is met?

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-flow

I have an overriden function that returns a flow of list and if the condition is not met, I emit an emptyList() to cover up the corner case:

```
override fun returnFlow(): Flow<List<Item>> {
    return combine(booleanFlow()) { items, boolean ->
        if (!boolean) {
            items
        } else {
            emptyList()
        }
    }
}
```

I want to remove the else {} logic and change it to only emitting a list when boolean is false. Ideally I would like something similar to this:

```
override fun returnFlow(): Flow<List<Item>> {
    return combine(booleanFlow()) { items, boolean ->
        while (!boolean) {
            items
        }
    }
}
```

Can I use something like cancelFlow() or return Nothing?

I tried [how to stop Kotlin flow when certain condition occurs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59956312/how-to-stop-kotlin-flow-when-certain-condition-occurs) and it doesn't work since the return type changes to `Flow<Unit>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`combineTransform`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.flow/combine-transform.html) instead of `combine`. Instead of always emitting the item returned by the lambda, this lets you choose whether or not to emit an item by calling `emit`.

```kotlin
override fun returnFlow(): Flow<List<Item>> {
    return combineTransform(booleanFlow()) { items, boolean ->
        if (!boolean) {
            emit(items)
        }
    }
}
```